# Key Hash With Securely-Optimal Setting : For Encryption vs For Password

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, hash, key

*Do you have to make a key hash with securely-optimum setting (eg. 100MB memlimit, 3 opslimit) for encryption ?*

So I'm making a text encryption function with javascript, using XChaCha20-Poly1305 and Argon2id. It's already working. The way it works is that everything processed in client's gadget. the key making (hashing) and encryption-decryption will happen in user's gadget (laptop, pc, smartphone). For hash making, user will give input of password, salt, opslimit and memlimit.

But something just hit me. Do the users really have to make the key with securely-optimum setting for Argon? The problem is in average affordable gadget that I've tested (laptop, smartphone) it takes about 15 seconds or more to make the Argon2id key with 100MB of memlimit. I just realized that all the Argon2id tutorial and security articles I read were about hashing for password, where the key will be saved to database for login purpose. But for encryption purpose where the server doesn't even save the key, does it really matter? Whether the memlimit is 100MB or just 12KB, seems doesn't make much different for me because we don't even save the key.

The only possibility I can think of for using optimum setting for Argon2id in encryption is if a hacker can "*extract*" the key from the encrypted text and from that key they will get the password if the setting is too low. But at that point I assume that the encrypted text already failed, the hacker already get the text decrypted.

I would really appreciate if everyone can enlighten me in this matter. I'm sure I've missed a lot of things in my research. Apologies for any weird wording since English is not my first language.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed important - essential, even - to use strong (slow) key derivation functions when doing password-based encryption. Even if you're not storing the key (or even something like a hash of the key), it's important to prevent an attacker from rapidly brute-forcing the password in an attempt to decrypt the data.

Think about the threat model here. You say:

> The only possibility I can think of for using optimum setting for Argon2id in encryption is if a hacker can "extract" the key from the encrypted text and from that key they will get the password if the setting is too low. But at that point I assume that the encrypted text already failed, the hacker already get the text decrypted.

You're implying that the valuable thing is the *password*, which is obviously false; the valuable thing is whatever the password protects. The password is just the easiest way to compromise that thing, so you have to prevent brute-forcing the password. (In practice, since many people reuse passwords, being able to brute-force one password can probably also be useful for compromising unrelated accounts, but that doesn't actually change the argument.) There is no way to "extract" a key from a ciphertext directly - that would be a massive, critical cryptographic flaw - but in almost all cases it is possible to quickly test a candidate key to see if it's correct, which means the obvious place to slow down brute-forcing is at the key derivation step.

Specifically for XChaCha20-Poly1305, as an AEAD cipher, an attacker can trivially verify a candidate key by decrypting a ciphertext and validating the authentication tag. However, this requires decrypting the whole text, and in many cases there's even faster options. For example, suppose you know the encrypted data is a JPEG image (or other file type that starts with a "magic number"). XOR the start of the ciphertext with the expected magic number, and you get the first N bytes (where N is the length of known plaintext, typically for magic numbers in files this will be 2-4) of the correct key's keystream. Then for each candidate key (derived from a candidate password), you use the nonce to generate the first N bytes of the keystream, and see if they match the result of the XOR. If they do, you have almost certainly found the correct key (decrypt the rest and validate the tag to confirm); if not, move on to the next candidate.

The important insights here are that *this check is easily parallelizable*, and that *unlike the key derivation, there's no feasible way to make that validation substantially harder to parallelize or otherwise more expensive*, so ***the only place to prevent this attack is at the key derivation step***. While the check is slower than simply testing for equality with a stored hash digest, it's not *much* slower - XChaCha20 is after all designed to be very efficient in software, and can be implemented in hardware if the attacker desires and has an FPGA or money to throw at an ASIC - and requires way less compute resources than Argon2 with even low cost parameters.

---

Now, with all that said... do you really need to make the key derivation take 15 seconds? That seems high; it could be reduced without coming close to being actually practical to brute-force the password. If you're running the memory cost that high, it might be OK to reduce the compute cost? The memory cost is mostly aimed at preventing parallel attacks; it does little against serial attacks, but computers (especially SIMD computing hardware, like GPUs) have spent the last decade+ getting more parallel much faster than they've been getting faster in serial, so parallel attacks are mostly what you're worried about. The usual advice for a reasonable key derivation cost on local hardware is whatever takes about *one* second, although obviously this depends on the sensitivity of whatever the key protects, and the tolerance of your users for long delays.

---

Finally, obligatory comment: you're rolling your own cryptosystem. That's much less dangerous than rolling your own primitives, but it's not enough less that the advice "don't roll your own" is inapplicable. In particular, *if you need to ask questions like this*, you probably shouldn't be designing a cryptosystem yourself. Better to ask the question than not, but please don't publish whatever you've built until you've had an applied cryptography expert look it over. There's a lot of room for subtle but major mistakes building something like this.

I'm also worried about your implementations of the relevant primitives. At least in browsers, neither your cipher nor your KDF are present in the standard library, and third party implementations vary wildly in their quality... *especially* if the implementation is pure Javascript. It's probably possible to write cryptographic primitives in JS that are correct even in the face of malformed input, and also don't leak any sensitive data via side channels, but I'd hate to try writing one for even a single JS engine, much less one that is safe across all engines where it might need to execute. Add the requirement that they perform acceptably (since if your implementation is 10% as fast as one in native code, then your key derivation needs to be 10x slower to achieve the same level of brute-force protection) and it's even more concerning.